# How to start 2 tmux sessions in rc.local?

Tags: raspberry-pi, tmux

This is my `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

#added2rebootRunTmuxReconnectSchedule
echo > /tmp/test1.txt
sleep 10
tmux new -d -s mqttListen 'python /home/pi/Documents/python/mqttReceive.py' 
#\; set -t mqttListen remain-on-exit on;
tmux new -d -s tsrbrclocal 'python /home/pi/Documents/python/tsrb430v3.py' 
#sudo -u pi bash /home/pi/tmux_start.sh &

exit 0
```

But on reboot only the 2nd one (`tsrbrclocal`) starts correctly. The other one shows a broken pipe error and is dead upon connecting to it. I must kill it, restart it and it works.

```
outside
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/python/mqttReceive.py", line 49, in <module>
    client.connect(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 839, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 962, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable



Pane is dead
```

where the word 'outside' is one of my debug logs and thereafter is the system log.

Comment: Can you tell if the error is from `tmux` or from Python? – "[It] is dead upon connecting to it. I must kill it" – Wait. You kill something that is dead? Or is the *Python program* dead and you kill the *pane/window/session/server* of `tmux`? (which is a different thing). My point is it's not clear what fails and what is dead. If it's the program then maybe you need to change its code. Some SO user sent you here because you presented the issue as a problem with `tmux` or `rc.local`. But maybe it's with Python. If so, without knowing the code nobody will help. Please [edit] and add information.

Comment: I also noticed now that I switched the raspberry pi from ethernet to wifi, the RPi connects to the router wirelessly but the next day it is no longer in the router's dhcp list, and of course no longer accesible on the network.  I go into the tmux session and I see the same error.  It's definitely not limited to power out issues, the disconnection is due to (perhaps) some configuration on the RPi that doesn't "keep trying" enough to reconnect once it has been disconnected for some reason, either on ethernet or wifi.